# Apache htaccess rewrite dynamic rewritebase

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I struggle with htaccess for production and local environment.
My production url is like: https://example.com/folder/file.php
Local I use: https://example.dev.local/app/folder/file.php

As you can see my local environment is using app which is a subfolder.
I want to prevent to set RewriteBase /app/

So affter searching I found answers like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
```

However I can get it work for my local enviroment.
My htaccess is:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect if not https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Urls ends with html
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index.php?rt=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]

# requests which are not static sources will be handled for the admin environment
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admin_cms/\.*\.(jpe?g|css|js|gif|png|woff2?|ttf|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin_cms/?(.*)$ admin.php?rt=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
```

an URL like:
https://example.dev.local/app/admin_cms/file.php should get matched for the second rule, but match only when I navigate to an url without app.

So my question is, how do I get it work that both (prod / local) work with the same htaccess?

Ps. I tried also `RewriteRule ^%{ENV:BASE}/admin_cms/?(.*)$ admin.php?rt=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]`

Comment: Would it not be better to remove `/app` from the local URL altogether?

Comment: Hi @MrWhite, I tot app, app2 etc so multiple sites. I my case each customer has in my local environment an appX. I want to prevent to create virtual hosts for each new customer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging I found an solution which worked for me. Maybe there are other solutions as well, please post this so I can update my answer with the different possibilities.

I made use of an non-capture group in my condition, and capture group in my rule.

```
# requests which are not static sources will be handled for the admin environment
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(?:\/[A-Za-z0-9]+)?/admin_cms/\.*\.(jpe?g|css|js|gif|png|woff2?|ttf|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+\/)?admin_cms/?(.*)$ $1admin.php?rt=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
```

To explain the rules:

**RewriteCond**

`!^(?:\/[A-Za-z0-9]+)?/admin_cms/\.*\.(jpe?g|css|js|gif|png|woff2?|ttf|ico)`

- ! = Not
- (?: = Create non-capture group which starts with / and follows A-Za-z or numeric
- )? = On end of the non-capture is the question mark which makes it optional, so it can have this group or can not
- (jpe?g.... = capture group so it should contain this extension

**RewriteRule**

```
^([A-Za-z0-9]+\/)?admin_cms/?(.*)$ $1admin.php?rt=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

- Makes the first group now as a capture, but it is optional, it will
  also appends the /. Position the / outside the optional group will
  make the pattern not work with an root url.
- Then for the rewrite we put the $1 as first group at the beginning
- $2 will be the part that will be passed to the rt

It will results in:

- https://example.dev.local/app/admin_cms/file.php =>
  https://example.dev.local/app/admin.php?rt=file.php
- https://example.dev.local/admin_cms/file.php =>
  https://example.dev.local/admin.php?rt=file.php